# How to update real time data with php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Currently I have a data file in dropbox that is uploaded every 15 seconds, I want to take this data, which has several different data types, and graph the real time data that the user selects on a website. I have a data server but my data is not on there. Is there any way for me to take this data from the file and graph it while also having a control panel that selects which data I want to graph.

Comment: Try asking more specific programming questions. Something like specific bugs and stuff like that. Or at least provide psuedocode for your idea or show what you tried.

Comment: It would help to narrow down your question. Are you trying to find out how to graph data? How to make a user control panel? How to access the dropbox file? If you've been able to take some first steps, then tell us what you've tried so far. If you're stuck on the first step, then it sounds like you need to ask a more specific question about how to let a PHP script access a dropbox file (make sure to say whether it's public or password-protected).

Comment: Sorry about being so vague, I am confused on what languages I need to use first off. Because the data is not on my server, do I not need to use mySQL, can I just use PHP and AJAX? Also how do I make a table of data types, so like temperature and humidity, so I can choose a certain data type. Like a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your web page using Ajax.  Note that if your refresh is set to every 15 seconds and your data comes in every 15 seconds, worst-case is that you will show data that's almost 30 seconds old if the timing of the data update and the Ajax refresh is unfortunate.

You probably want to check for new data using Ajax more frequently, depending on your specific needs.  On the server side, cache the result of the Ajax update to avoid too much duplicate processing.

To create the data that you return from the Ajax query, open and process the data file.  No need for MySQL.  You can use the timestamp of the file to invalidate the result cache I suggest in the previous paragraph.

There are many JavaScript based charting libraries that can update via Ajax.  Here's a good starting point:

[Graphing JavaScript Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426/graphing-javascript-library)